# Error in stored procedures call from a stored procedure in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, stored-procedures, amazon-redshift

I have created a final stored procedure consisting of two stored procedure calls.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE schema.master_stored_procedure()
AS $$
BEGIN

RAISE INFO 'Job-1 starting';
CALL stored_procedure_1();
RAISE INFO 'Job-1 Finished';

RAISE INFO 'Job-2 starting';
CALL stored_procedure_2();
RAISE INFO 'Job-2 Finished';

END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
;
```

Both stored_procedure_1 and stored_procedure_2 are executing properly when called individually.
But when calling the final stored procedure it throws the following error:

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
call master_stored_procedure()

ERROR: procedure master_stored_procedure() does not exist
  Hint: No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.
1 statement failed.
```

Comment: This is procedure `schema.master_stored_procedure`. Owned by `schema`. Which user are you connected to when calling `master_stored_procedure`?

Comment: Your error does not come from any of your procedures posted. It comes from whatever/however you call `schema,master_stored_procedure()` . Please post that. Possibility:  you are missing the necessary grants.

Comment: Why have you tagged "Oracle"? Your procedure appears to be written for PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Littlefoot Yes, the user I am connected to is the same which I have used to create it.

@Belayer I am using the below command to call:
`call master_stored_procedure()`

@MT0 Yes my bad I have removed it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the schema name before the procedure name. Try this:

```
schema.master_stored_procedure();
```